# CockroachDB or mariaDB cluster for many read slaves, 1 master?

Tags: mariadb, cockroachdb

I am after a recommendation on the following setup...

1 Master that has all tables.

- 1 main table ( table A ) that master will write to, and read. often.
- 5+ tables ( tables B+ ) master will read from these not often, does not need to be most recent updated data ( within 24hrs )

4+ slaves that have all tables.

- will only read from table A, does not need to be most recent updated data (within 24hrs ).
- will read and write to tables B+ often. ( each slave will have its own table and does not need to sync to other slaves )

Tables B rows will have a relation to table A for querying.

My plan is to have the master to setup the service for all clients with main details in table A.
Individual function of the service will be split out to different nodes/slaves. These functions will do a lot of read/writes to tables B ( each slave to its own table ).
I don't want those read/writes to overload the master database tho (or other slaves). I do want them to sync to the master at most every 24hrs. So the master can get the updated data when it checks ( won't be often ). When it reads though, if it has not been synced live it does not matter as it will read it again the next day.

Maybe I can have a setting on the slaves that syncing to master is not urgent, so do it when network is quiet? Same with syncing to other slaves, not urgent.

I am familiar with MariaDB, but wondering if CockroachDB may be better for such a setup if anyone recommends it? Ease of use, setup and reliability?

Comment: How many writes per second?  Look into Galera.

Comment: With CockroachDB, **every** node is a master!

Answer (score 0):

QPS and the size of the writes and reads is important to decided what will work or not. With CockroachDB you don't have masters and slaves so you can try with the minimum recommended size of three nodes (which will tolerate a single node failure). Depending on the load and the type of servers you are using that may be enough or require adding more nodes.

Comment: but when you write to one node, doesnt that then replicate to all the nodes? is it doesnt decrease the load on any of the other node.